# why i can't update anything? (onModifierFinished, runOnUpdateThread, registerUpdateHandler...) AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine

i'm doing my first andengine project, so i'm building a framework to work with it. I have a typical ResourceManager and a SceneManager (both Singleton).

Until here, all ok. Then i start to make MyScenes (SceneManager -> MyScene), i create all ok, but when i register handlers or listener to update something (like attach, dettach objects or setVisible or even setScreen), nothing works. Like if there are not any GameLoop.

I use GLES2-Anchor center.

In my GameBaseActivity i setup the ResourceManager:

```
   rm.setup(Game.this, this.getEngine(), this.getApplicationContext(), CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT, 1f, 1f);
```

In ResourceManager, mEngine is static.

In MyScene, first createScene() method at then end call to populatesScene() method, where i set animations to entities but it doesn't update:

```
this.registerUpdateHandler(new IUpdateHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {

                Log.d("2","this show in log");
               ResourceManager.g_menu_manual.getSprite().setVisible(true);

        }
        @Override public void reset() {}
    });
```

also, i have this Modifier:

```
 SequenceEntityModifier sem = new SequenceEntityModifier(moveLeft){     
        @Override
        public void onModifierFinished(final IModifier<IEntity> pModifier,final IEntity pItem) {
            Log.d("2","this show in log");

             ResourceManager.mEngine.runOnUpdateThread(new Runnable() {
                 @Override
                 public void run() {
                     ResourceManager.g_menu_manual.getSprite().setVisible(true);
                 }
         });
```

Log always shows the messages, but bots updates never works. 
If i setVisibility when createScene() or populatesScene() all is alright.

What i'm doing wrong with updates?

Answer (score 0):

Register the update handler to the scene, not the engine.

Also entity modifiers should be registered to entities with the registerEntityModifier method.

Comment: Thanks but that's not the problem.

this.registerUpdateHandler.... this references the class Myscene, which extends Scene.

And with the Modifier after i set the SequenceEntityModifier, of course i register it to the entity with:

ResourceManager.g_menu_titulo.getSprite().registerEntityModifier(sem);